# Small difference between print in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, printing, python-3.3

I'm working on modifying a Python 2 script so that it works and Python 3 and is backwards compatible to Python 2. Here is a simplified example for the code snippet I'm having trouble with:

```
file = open('test.txt', 'w')
for item in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    print >> file, item,

print >> file
file.close()
```

As I understand it, the trailing comma causes a space instead of a linefeed. However, if you run the example, you'll see that is not always the case. On the last iteration of the for loop, there is no space after the letter. Here is my current solution to get the same result in Python 2 and 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function

file = open('test.txt', 'w')
items = ['a', 'b', 'c']
last_index = len(items) - 1
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    end = ' ' if i < last_index else ''
    print(item, end=end, file=file)

print(file=file)
file.close()
```

But this is horribly ugly. My question is this: Is there a cleaner way to do this? Note: I know this particular example is much more easily solved with a join, but please just trust me when I tell you that won't work in my case because there is extra processing that takes place inside the for loop. When answering, please assume the basic structure of the code must remain the same.

Comment: What type of *extra processing* are you doing inside the loop? You can move that extra processing to a function or generator and write the returned iterable using `str.join`.

Comment: I suppose combining a generator with a join is a workable solution. Thanks, I didn't think of that. Please answer my question and I will accept it.

Comment: I've undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.join` or the `csv` module for this.

And if you're doing some processing on the items of the list then you can move that processing to a generator and then join the returned value using `str.join`

```
def gen(x):
    #do something here
    #yield something

with open('file.txt') as f:
    f.write(' '.join(x for x in gen(items)))
```

Using `csv` module:

```
import csv
with open('file.txt') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    writer.writerow(list(gen(items)))
```

Comment: Come on... at least read OP's text: "[...] Note: I know this particular example is much more easily solved with a join, [...]"

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes I've updated my answer after OP's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633594/small-difference-between-print-in-python-2-and-python-3#comment32700642_21633594).

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's probably the best solution in my case. However, I think it's worth mentioning (since I am striving for backward compatibility) that in order to use with, an import is neededed: from __future__ import with_statement

Comment: Also, join(x for x in gen(items)) is a bit verbose. join(gen(items)) does just fine.

Comment: @BradPitcher Yes, you can use that if you're sure that the items returned by the generator are always going to be strings.

Comment: `with` statement is not compulsory, it is just a good practice to open file using the `with` statement, it makes sure that the file gets closed even if an exception occurs. Of course, if you're using a very old version(2.5) of Python then you'll need an import.